# Echo every image for Member ID

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 <?php require('includes/config.php');
include("includes/conf_proc.php");

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }

//define page title
$title = 'Account Page';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 

$img_query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE memberID='".$_SESSION['memberID']."'";
$img = mysqli_query($conn, $img_query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($img);


?>

<div class="container">

    <h2 style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:15px;">User account</h2>
        <div class="row" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:90px">
                <?php
                    echo '<img src="./demo/covers/'.$rows['image'].'" />';
                    echo $num_row;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Hi guys,As u can see echo is going to show picture that Loged in member downloaded.But i dont know how to create loop where i can show every picture member downloaded ? All that database has is ID,MemberID and Pcuture name.
So for example,echo every picture that has Member ID  2.
Should i use JOIN ?

Comment: _“Should i use JOIN ?”_ – no, of course not. JOINs are for _join_-ing data from several tables together (or from one table with itself, if there’s columns cross-referencing each other) – but you only have one very simple table here. So all you need is a loop – and even the very basic examples in the manual on [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) could have shown you how that works.

Comment: Tnx for the clarification mate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in a `while` loop.

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');
include("includes/conf_proc.php");

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }

//define page title
$title = 'Account Page';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 

$img_query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE memberID='".$_SESSION['memberID']."'";
$img = mysqli_query($conn, $img_query);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($img);


?>
    <div class="container">

    <h2 style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:15px;">User account</h2>
    <?php
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($img))
    {
    ?>
        <div class="row" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:90px">
                <?php
                    echo '<img src="./demo/covers/'.$rows['image'].'" />';
                    echo $num_row;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </div>
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: I see,tnx a lot mate !